# Call() usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Javascript object which has key as function name and value as function.

```
   var fnObj = { getReport: [Function], getAccountDetail: [Function] }
```

method invoke using call

```
fnObj['getReport'].call(null,arg1,arg2); // since its dynamic method call so using call()
```

or without call()

```
 var a =  fnObj['getReport'](arg1,arg2);
```

dynamic function

```
getReport:function(arg1,arg2){
    //it will do some execution with arg1 and arg2
    return  {'some': 'result'};
}
```

Which way of call method invoke is correct?

Comment: They're both correct, but they're different. It totally depends on what you want to happen.

Comment: fnObj.getReport( .. )

Comment: what do you mean by correct? in both ways you're executing the function, the different is the `this` within the function, using `.call` and `null`, `this = window` and callingt it directly `this` is `fnObj`.

Comment: Since you don't need to change the context of 'this' in the function, you should invoke the function directly without .call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between those two methods is the value of `this` inside the function.

When you [explicitly set it to `null`](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ggdLd6/) it will be `null` (unless you aren't in strict mode, in which case it will be the default object), [when you don't](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ggdLd6/1/) it will be the value of `fnObj`.

Which is correct (assuming that one is not) will depend on what the function does with `this` (which we can't tell because you haven't shared that code).

---

Re update:

Since you don't use `this` in the functions, it doesn't make a difference (except that using `call` is more long-winded and implies that the value of `this` matters when a maintainer comes along to read the code).

Comment: this is wrong, when you use `null` as the first parameter in `.call`, `this` will be the global object, for browser it will be the `window` object

Comment: @Luizgrs why don't you try that out with a simple test?

Comment: @Pointy I do tried it, I got the `this = global` in node.js and `window` in Chrome, as Quentin updated the answer, "use strict" can make this behavior change and `null` will be `null`

Comment: @Luizgrs yes you're right - I've been working in strict mode for so long I kind-of forget all the old stuff :)

Comment: Thanks Quentin, Pointy and Luizgrs

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be.

`fnObj.getReport(arg1, arg2);`

Unless you have specific *needs*.